# Recommended way to handle AngularJS Directive data

Tags: angularjs

I regularly see examples such as `<calendar events="a.appointments"></calendar>` in which data assigned within a controller is passed in to a directive via an attribute binding.

The code below shows an alternative solution, in which the required data is gathered directly within the directive `link` function. Using this approach eliminates the need for a separate controller.

diary.html

```
<calendar></calendar>
```

calendar.js

```
angular.module('diary').
directive('calendar', ['AppointmentsService', function(AppointmentsService) {
    return {
        template: 'calendar.html',

        scope: {},

        link: function($scope) {
            $scope.events = {};

            AppointmentsService.getAppointments().then(function(result) {
                $scope.events = result;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Is this a suitable or ultimately flawed approach to take?

Answer (score 0):

If your `calendar` directive is completely decoupled from everything, it is absolutely fine approach to go for. However, if you need a certain communication between `calendar` and, let's say, `events-tracker` directive, you might want to enclose them in a parent controller. Or if you have a collections of `calendar` directives on a single page (with an option to remove or add new calendar), then passing the data by reference is a way to go as well.

**EDIT**
`e.appointments` are probably passed to `calendar` through scope, not attribute, i.e. calendar having isolated scope with `events` field.

Answer (score 0):

Having thought about this some more, I've realised the alternative solution does have a flaw and it's a reusability issue.

When providing `events` through an attribute binding to the directive's isolate scope, the source of the data is totally flexible.

Fetching the appointments directly within the `link` function of the directive however, creates a specific dependency on `AppointmentsService` as the data source.